# addEventListener - how to make if not clicked statement

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

i have the problem with addEventListener. Thing i want to carry out is that on click selected .nav-item gets the active class(Bootstrap) and that works. Problem that i don't know how to make an "if not clicked" statement that removes class active when the new active class is clicked. Sorry for the language im having difficulty explaining this.

```
      let navItems = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item");
        
    navItems.forEach(navitem => {
        navitem.addEventListener("click", function(){
            navitem.classList.add("active");
              let clicked = true;
            if(clicked != true){

                navitem.classList.remove("active");
            }
        });
 
   })
```

Code is wrong for sure but i dont know how to fix this. Thanks! Ive tried to do forEach on navItems and i get an error.

Comment: There is no Node or express in this question

Comment: Use toggle instead `navitem.classList.toggle("active");`

Comment: @epascarello Problem is that there are 3 nav-items and if I use toggle they can be all active or all without active class.Idea is that 1 is active other 2 are not.

Comment: So you select the others and remove the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use toggle, loop over all the items and remove the class if it is not the current one.

```js
let navItems = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item");

const removeSelected = active => navItems.forEach(elem => {
  if (elem != active) elem.classList.remove("active");
})

navItems.forEach(navitem => {
  navitem.addEventListener("click", function() {
    navitem.classList.toggle("active"); // or add if something has to be selected
    removeSelected(navitem);
  });

})
```

```css
.active { background: #FCF; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item">1</li>
  <li class="nav-item">2</li>
  <li class="nav-item">3</li>
  <li class="nav-item">4</li>
  <li class="nav-item">5</li>
  <li class="nav-item">6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you just please explain this line of code "removeSelected = active => navItems.forEach". Im not that far jet what "active => navItems" means in this case.

Comment: `function removeSelected (active) { navItems.forEach( function(elem) {});}`

Answer (score 2):

As far as i unterstand you want to remove the class "active" from the previously clicked nav-item if another nav-item is clicked. I would do this by saving the current active nav-item:

```
let navItems = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item");
let activeNavItem = document.querySelector(".nav-item.active");

navItems.forEach(navitem => {
    navitem.addEventListener("click", function(){
        navitem.classList.add("active");

        if(activeNavItem != null){
            activeNavItem.classList.remove("active");
        }

        activeNavItem = navitem;
    }); 
})
```

EDIT:
I changed the code so the first active item is already stored on load.

Comment: Ok this solved most of the problem. When the page loads  nav-item[0] is active(HOME), and if its not clicked first it wont remove active class, for nav-item[1] and nav-item[2] it works.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to remove all 'active' classes found
and then add to current selection.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title> .active settings </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
<!-- Modified from:
     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62718281/addeventlistener-how-to-make-if-not-clicked-statement/62718506#62718506
-->
<style>
 .active { background: cyan; }
 ul { width: 10em; border: 1px solid black; }
 li:hover { background-color: orange; }
</style>
</head><body>
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item">1</li>
  <li class="nav-item">2</li>
  <li class="nav-item">3</li>
  <li class="nav-item">4</li>
  <li class="nav-item">5</li>
  <li class="nav-item">6</li>
</ul>
<script>
console.clear();

let navItems = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item");
    
navItems.forEach(navitem => {
  navitem.addEventListener("click", function(){
  
// remove class from all .nav-item found (not option below)
    navItems.forEach( item => item.classList.remove("active") );
// OPTION: Comment OUT above line for saving status of current selections

// toggle display of current .nav-item selection
    navitem.classList.toggle("active");
  });
})
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Modified to maintain multiple selections as well as display only one selection

Answer (score 0):

probably you want something like this

```js
var nav=document.querySelector(".nav")
var navitem=document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item")


        
        nav.addEventListener("click", function(e){
             navitem.forEach(el=>{
                el.setAttribute("class", " nav-item");
             })
            e.target.classList.add("active");
              
   })
```

```css
#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}


.active{
  background:green
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-message">
<div class="nav">

  <div class="nav-item">item1</div>
  <div class="nav-item">item1</div>
  <div class="nav-item">item1</div>
  <div class="nav-item">item1</div>
  <div class="nav-item">item1</div>

</div>
</div>
```